# Word 2013: how do I make zoom level sticky?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, accessibility

Word's default display size is almost always too small for me.  Because I use Word only at work and most of our documents use a standard template, I can say with a fair degree of certainty what zoom level I'd actually like to set as a default.  (It'd be far easier to change it on a few occasions than having to change it *almost every single time*, which is the current situation.)  I can find no settings under Options nor on the View section of the ribbon.  How can I do this?

I'm using Office 2013 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.  I am *not* interested in changing my Windows-wide settings; everything else is working fine (so far) and I don't want to mess that up.  I just need to change Word.

I've tagged this Word 2013 because that's what I'm using, but I don't remember a way to do this at a prior employer in Word 2007 either.  I haven't used Word 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Before I start, I have to ask the question: How are you changing your zoom? Are you clicking View > Zoom and setting it from there? If you are, there's a much easier way to zoom: Hold ctrl, then scroll your mouse wheel. I change zoom all the time and this is so effective I haven't seen the need to do anything else.

However, if you're looking for a more automatic solution then you can run a macro to set the zoom every time you open a document. Place the macros in your Normal template. (see http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm and follow the 2010 instructions. 2013 should be almost identical)

```
Sub AutoOpen()
On Error GoTo errhandler
ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3 'print layout
ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 130

errhandler:
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub AutoNew()
On Error GoTo errhandler
ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3 'print layout
ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 130

errhandler:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This macro was directly copied from Stefan Blom at http://bit.ly/1oJ8TeN.

Comment: Yes, view -> zoom -> type number.  Thanks for pointing out an easier way while I pursue the macro!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!

Comment: Good get, I say.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [similar discussion](http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/157999-word-2010-how-do-i-change-default-viewing-zoom-document.html) related to default Zoom level on Seven Forums. They have discussed a way of using Macros to achieve the desired behavior.